# Get all non-word characters excluding those in a url

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to write a regex in python that will match all non-word characters (spaces, slashes, colons, etc.) excluding those that exist in a url. I know I can get all non-word characters with `\W+` and I also have a regex to get urls: `https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*[\w\/\-]+|https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*|[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*\/[\w\/\-]+` but I can't figure out a way to combine them. What would be the best way to get what I need here?

**EDIT**

To clarify, I am trying to split on this regex. So when I attempt to using `re.split()` with the following regex: `https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*[\w\/\-]+|https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*|[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*\/[\w\/\-]+|(\W)` I end up with something like the following:

INPUT:
this is a test: https://www.google.com

OUTPUT:
['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'test', ':', '', ' ', '', None, '']

What I'm hoping to get is this:
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'https://www.google.com']

This is how I'm splitting:

```
import re

message = 'this is a test: https://www.google.com'
re.split("https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*[\w\/\-]+|https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a- zA-Z]*|[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*\/[\w\/\-]+|(\W)", message)
```

Comment: Use the "best regex trick ever": capture what you need, just match what you do not need. So, use ``https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*[\w\/\-]+|https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*|[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*\/[\w\/\-]+|(\W)`` and grab Group 1 value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please see my edit. This regex is correct but I seem to be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a reverse logic, match a URL pattern or any one or more word chars:

```py
import re
rx = r"https*://[\w.]+\.[\w/-]*|[\w.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*/[\w/-]+|\w+"
message = 'this is a test: https://www.google.com'
print( re.findall(rx, message) )
# => ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'https://www.google.com']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Hl9YST).

Note I shortened your URL pattern, you had two similar alternatives, `https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*[\w\/\-]+` and `https*:\/\/[\w\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]*`, where `[a-zA-Z]*` is redundant as it matches any zero or more letters and the next `[\w\/\-]+` pattern requires one or more letters, `/` or `-` chars. You also do not have to escape dots inside character classes and slashes, the unnecessary escapes are removed here.